# Inconsisent gap between number and text

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography

I got strange spacing issues. There is number and each text parallel. And there is different spacing between 1, 4, 7 and 'each' text. How can we fix this issue or it can't be fixed. I have not used any spacing and extra css properties.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Spectral');

.bigger {
  font-size: 40px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="bigger">81</span>
  <small>each</small>
</p> <br>
<p>
  <span class="bigger">84</span>
  <small>each</small>
</p> <br>
<p>
  <span class="bigger">87</span>
  <small>each</small>
</p> <br>
```

Comment: you can use the `letter-spacing` for reducing the space between letters

Comment: Those spaces are `kerning`.

Comment: @Kumar, did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the issue of letter spacing of the font. You should use a `monospace` font to achieve same spacing for all characters.

Try the below snippet.

```css
.bigger {
  font-size: 40px;
}

p {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="bigger">81</span>
  <small>each</small>
</p> <br>
<p>
  <span class="bigger">84</span>
  <small>each</small>
</p> <br>
<p>
  <span class="bigger">87</span>
  <small>each</small>
</p> <br>
```

Comment: Those spaces are `kerning` not letter spacing, I guess

Comment: I didn't mean the css `letter-spacing` brother. It is the spacing defined in font file. Since he didn't used a monospace font, the spacing will vary for each character. That's why I suggested him to use a monospace font. You can see the snippet that the arrangement is done equally. @AbhishekPandey

Comment: I used the term `letter spacing of the font` because I am didn't aware of the terminology `kerning`. Thanks for the term.

Comment: Now you know the term ;) happy coding

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round actually? As far as I know in a monospaced font every letter gets the same fixed amount of space to live in. So of course a narrow letter will have more space around it than a wide letter. A proportional typeface on the other hand usually tries to reduce this irregular spacing? It looks like there is still a bigger space between `87` and `each`.

Comment: You don't have to use a different looking monospace font — you can possibly solve it with your original font. See my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Although using a monospace font is a nice workaround, you could solve this with your original font if it has the correct OpenType features.

The difference in the space that a digit occupies is caused by the width of the digit (as opposed to kerning or letter spacing, as suggested in the other answers). The width is proportional — the 1 is narrower than the 4.

But a font can also offer *tabular figures*, where each digit is of equal width:

[image: Image from https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/proportional-vs-tabular-figures]

You can enable this in CSS with `font-feature-settings: 'tnum';`. Or to use other OpenType features and take care of browser inconsistencies, see [Utility OpenType](http://utility-opentype.kennethormandy.com/).

Comment: This would be much more useful if it noted whether the specific font in the question supports this and, more generically, how to check.

Comment: @Caleb Good point. Open Sans [does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sans#Variants), but I don't know if the version hosted by Google does. In any case, you can find out by checking with your font supplier, or simply testing it out with `font-feature-settings: 'tnum'`.

Answer (score 2):

The character 1 (and 7 sometimes) would usually be spaced out in most fonts. If you want uniform spacing, you should consider using monospace fonts.

Another improvement that you can make to your code is removing the spaces between tags.

Please check the code below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Spectral');

.bigger {
  font-size: 40px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="bigger">81</span><small>each</small>
</p> <br>
<p>
  <span class="bigger">84</span><small>each</small>
</p> <br>
<p>
  <span class="bigger">87</span><small>each</small>
</p> <br>
```